# Send email of a row's data if two cells in that row don't match

Tags: google-apps-script

Hey there Sheet Wizards.

- Column A - Timestamp
- Column B - Order ID Barcode
- Column C - Product ID Barcode (Packing Slip)
- Column D - Product ID Barcode (On Product)

I have spreadsheets from employees from scanned barcode data, but sometimes they miss the proper barcode. I need a data validation for them as they scan.

Employee scans packing slip, then the product, and populates the above mentioned columns, and I'd like to send an email alert to 2 email addresses when column C and column D report different values.

(edit) The email needs only to list the value of each column.

Answer (score 1):

So I assume Column C and Column D should show the same product ID if your employee scans it correctly?

In that case, just create another column, column E, with the following formula:

```
=arrayformula(if(C:C=D:D,true,false))
```

Insert this formula at the top of the new column.

Then using google apps script, create a function where if column E'value = false, send email to your 2 email addresses containing the value of the row with issues.

```
  function sendEmailIfError(){
  let targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("insert your sheet name");
  let lastRowTargetSheet = targetSheet.getLastRow();
  for (let i = lastRowTargetSheet ; i>0 ; i --){
    checker = targetSheet.getRange("E"+[i]).getValue()
    if (checker == "false"){
      <insert email function here>
    } break
  }
}
```

This function has to be run on an On edit Trigger.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll go try it out now!

Comment: Looks like this line is throwing an error my way on not defining E.


    checker = targetSheet.getRange(E[i]).getValue()
.

ReferenceError: E is not defined

Comment: you need to insert targetSheet.getRange(`E${[i]}`).getValue().
Do read up on the documentation provided by google apps script , get range can take in A1 notation but the input has to be a string.
try using template literal which is defined by 2 back ticks.